# Split string correctly with Regex in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have a string of this type:

```
<p> Everything is divided in paragraphs </p>
<h4> or hi's with i=1,2,...,6.</h4>
<div> Ah, and also divs </div>
```

I wanted to split this string using regex, so I wrote this one: `/(<\/?(p|(h\d)|(div))>)/g`, that when I try in websites like [this one](https://regexr.com/3ff0o) says it's a correct regular expression for what I want, but when I split it, I get partial portions of the text, like an isolated p or `undefined` between strings. How could I achieve manipulate the string to get an array of the form:

```
['<p>',
'Everything is divided in paragraphs',
 '</p>',
'<h4>', ...
 '</div>']
```

Comment: What do you want to get in the result?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why the website deleted half of my question. Let me add the rest.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Regex is almost certainly not the answer here.

Comment: Added the missing part.

Comment: @iam_agf Check my updated answer. Is it ok? Seems like doing what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated. Is this what you trying to do?

```js
let data = `<p> Everything is divided in paragraphs </p>
<h4> or hi's with i=1,2,...,6.</h4>
<div> Ah, and also divs </div>`;

// Sptlit and dont capture subgroups, also do not memorize
// newlines and filter empty elements
const m = data.split(/\n*(<\/?(?:p|(?:h\d)|(?:div))>)\n*/).filter(i => i);

console.log(m)
```